# SSRS - Formula inside IIF statement

Tags: reporting-services, expression

Im trying to create an IIF statement on SSRS where one of the results have an expression inside. I could only find examples with plain text but wanted to no how i can mix text and this expression as a result:

This is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
=IIf(Sum(Fields!BytesTotal.Value, "dataset_traffic") = 0,
   "No data available",
   "Your data is 'Sum(Fields!BytesTotal.Value, "dataset_traffic")/1073741824'"
)
```

How can i declare an expression inside an IIF result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
=IIf(
   Sum(Fields!BytesTotal.Value, "dataset_traffic") = 0,
   "No data available",
   "Your data is " & Sum(Fields!BytesTotal.Value, "dataset_traffic")/1073741824
)
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Yep. exactly what i was looking for.